# Javascript error on TinyMCE

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm encountering a javascript error in a TinyMCE dialogue box when I try to insert a file into content. here's what I get: Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ####.com/editor/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/Archiv/php/fileLoader.php?file=javascript 165

Initially I assumed the path was broken so I went over my links and realized everything was fine. I assumed it might have been a browser compatibility issue but tests on Safari, Firefox and even, sadly, IExplorer proved this wasn't the case. I then assumed the fault could have been with my version of TinyMCE and patched it with new files to no success. I'm at wits end! Please help, anyone.

This is the fileLoader.php:

```
 <?php

switch($_GET['file']){
    # Javascript files
    case 'javascript':
        header('Content-type: text/javascript');
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tiny_mce_popup.js')."\r\n\r\n";
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'flash_detect_min.js')."\r\n\r\n";
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jquery' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jquery-1.3.2.min.js')."\r\n\r\n";      
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jquery' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js')."\r\n\r\n";
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'SWFupload' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'swfupload.min.js')."\r\n\r\n";      
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'json2.min.js')."\r\n\r\n";
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'SWFupload' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'handlers.min.js')."\r\n\r\n";       
        readfile('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'archiv.min.js');        
        break;

    # default 404
    default:
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, its likely an issue with how you have implemented the javascript code. The error refers to getting length of an array or string, but in this case, the variable is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the PHP is functioning as intended.  The error you're mentioning is a Javascript error, as PHP does not use `.length` you won't see the error `get length of undefined` come from PHP.

Try including all of your JS files manually and see where the error is.  It's likely one of the libraries is expecting an element to be on the page that isn't.  If they're minified I would recommend using [Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).